# AutoUpdate Total box using mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm

Currently I want the calculations to be dynamic and change on per key stroke. I am trying to do this using MVVM but not entirely sure how.

In the view Model:

```
public int? Duration { get { return _seb.Duration; } set { _seb.Duration = value;} }
public decimal? Amount { get { return _seb.AmountPer; } set { _seb.AmountPer = value;} }
```

I have a `total` Variable And would like it to be constantly updated. May I ask how do I do this.

I tried something like this but no luck

```
public decimal? Total {get { return _seb.Total; } set { _seb.Total = Amount*Duration; }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by raising the ProperyChanged event of the total property when either of the other two property changes.

```
public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int? _duration;
    private decimal? _amount;

    public int? Duration
    {
        get { return _duration; }
        set
        {
            if (_duration != value)
            {
                _duration = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Duration");
                RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal? Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set
        {
            if (_amount != value)
            {
                _amount = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Amount");
                RaisePropertyChanged("Total");
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal? Total
    {
        get
        {
            if (Amount.HasValue && Duration.HasValue)
                return Amount.Value * Duration.Value;

            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely think this is the right approach. Just some slight complications. I got "A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Total'

Comment: My current binding set up `Text="{Binding Total, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`

Comment: Ok but do you need to change the Total from the View or just display it? Forget the UpdateSourceTrigger part if you only wish to listen to changes of Total. `Text="{Binding Total, Mode=OneWay}`

Comment: There is no way of knowing what Amount and Duration should be if you change the Total in the UI, unless you have a standard ratio set.

Comment: The oneway mode defines one way from the viewmodel to the view. If you want a one way that goes from the view eg. only writes the value to the viewmodel and doesnt read you should use Mode=OneWayToSource.

Comment: I'm quite close to getting it. How do i Resolve this? `Error 9 The name 'RaisePropertyChanged' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: It's a method of the BaseViewModel class. To me it seems you do not have any understanding of how MVVM pattern is applied. Maybe you first go and learn the basics and how INotifyPropertyChanged interface is implemented and used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is not a single way to make MVVM work. It's a pattern, not a framework. It's basically about implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and `ICommand` and bind it to WPF

Comment: Thank you for your help! was great and very detailed. Works perfectly now

Comment: One last question, How do I make a Case to use previous value if existed, Otherwise Create new one For total.

Comment: You can always have a private _total variable in which you store the total value. Something like `if(_total == null) { _total = Amount * Duration; } return _total;`

Answer (score 0):

You must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and put the formula on get of the total property

```
public int? Duration 
{ 
  get 
  { 
     return _seb.Duration; 
  } 
  set
  { 
    _seb.Duration = value; 
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Total")
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show your xaml view as well.

Assuming you are using a textbox, bound to some property in your ViewModel, you can make sure that that property is updated whenever the textbox propery changes by doing something like this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding MyVmProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />
```